# $L^2$ norm and $L^{\infty}$ inequality for periodic smooth functions

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces, integral-inequality

Let $\varphi \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{T}^n,\mathbb{C})$ (i.e. just smooth periodic complex-valued function) and $f \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{T}^n,\mathbb{C}^m)$. Then I was wondering if the following is true:

$$
\|\varphi f\|_{2} \leq \|\varphi\|_{\infty}\|f\|_{2}
$$.
Where the $\|\cdot \|_{2}$ is $L^2-$norm and $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$ is the sup-norm which are defined in this case to be

$$
\|f\|_{2} := \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{\frac{n}{2}}} \Bigg(\int_{\mathbb{T}^n} f \cdot f \Bigg)^{1/2} \quad \text{where $'\cdot'$ represents the Hermitian product.} 
$$
and
$$
\|f\|_{\infty} = \sup_{\mathbb{T}^n}\{|f|\}
$$
also we denote $|f| = (f \cdot f)^{1/2}$.

I managed to prove the following
$$
\|f\|_2 \leq \|f\|_{\infty}
$$
as follows
$$ 
|f| \leq \sup_{\mathbb{T}^n} |f|
$$
$$
\implies |f| \leq \|f\|_{\infty} \implies |f|^2 \leq \|f\|_{\infty}^2
$$
hence
$$
\int_{\mathbb{T}^n} |f|^2 d\mu \leq \int_{\mathbb{T}^n} \|f\|_{\infty}^2 d\mu = \|f\|_{\infty}^2 \int_{\mathbb{T}^n} 1 d\mu = \|f\|_{\infty}^2  \mu(\mathbb{T}^n)
$$
and taking square roots on both sides,
$$
\Bigg(\int_{\mathbb{T}^n} |f|^2 d\mu \Bigg)^{1/2} \leq  \|f\|_{\infty}  \mu(\mathbb{T}^n)^{1/2}
$$
which gives
$$
\Bigg(\int_{\mathbb{T}^n} f \cdot f \quad d\mu \Bigg)^{1/2} \leq  \|f\|_{\infty}  \mu(\mathbb{T}^n)^{1/2}
$$
multiplying $\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}}$ both sides, we obtain
$$
\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}}\Bigg(\int_{\mathbb{T}^n} f \cdot f \quad d\mu \Bigg)^{1/2} \leq  \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}}\|f\|_{\infty}  \mu(\mathbb{T}^n)^{1/2}
$$
and hence by using the fact that $\mu(\mathbb{T}^n) = (2\pi)^n$, we have
$$
\|f\|_{2} \leq \|f\|_{\infty}
$$
But this seems not so useful.
I was proceeding by showing
$$
\|\varphi f\|_2 \leq \|\varphi\|_{2}\|f\|_2
$$
which I think is False even with the given conditions and hence the above work seems useless.

Summary : I need to prove
$$
\|\varphi f\|_{2} \leq \|\varphi\|_{\infty}\|f\|_{2}
$$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that integrals are monotonic, so if $f\leq g$ a.e. then $\int f\leq \int g$. Thus if $g\geq 0$ a.e. and $f_1\leq f_2$ a.e. you get $f_1g\leq f_2g$ a.e. and thus $\int f_1g\leq \int f_2 g$.

So now see that $|\phi|\leq \|\phi\|_\infty$ a.e. and $(\phi f)\cdot(\phi f) = |\phi|^2 |f|^2$ and $|f|^2\geq 0$.

So using this we get
$$ \|\phi f\|_2 \leq  \Big\|\|\phi\|_\infty f\Big\|_2$$
and as $\|\phi\|_\infty$ is a scalar this is
$$ \|\phi\|_\infty \|f\|_2$$